# ¿Cómo traducir "He posed a conjecture"?

Tags: traducción

Estoy en duda sobre cómo traducir esta frase al español.

Algunos candidatos son:

- Propuso una conjetura
- Posó una conjectura
- Emitió una conjetura

Pero ninguno me convence.
"Conjeturó" no cuadra muy bien con lo que estoy escribiendo.

Comment: Si es en ámbito matemático, _conjeturar_ también se usa. Véase el artículo sobre la [conjetura de Goldbach](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjetura_de_Goldbach) por ejemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La mejor combinación es: "formular/plantear una conjetura/hipótesis".